# crons are not working correctly - schedule / laradock

Tags: laravel, redis, cron, supervisord, laradock

I have an application in Laravel.
In it I am using Laradock to facilitate the creation of containers.

The containers used are:

- caddy
- mysql
- phpmyadmin
- redis
- php-worker
- laravel-horizon

I set up some crons in Laravel Scheduler and they worked correctly in the early days, however, they always end up falling on the second or third day and I have no error log about it.

How to proceed? I have a feeling that the redis service has just stopped working.
I always have to restart php-worker and laravel-horizon and manually run the crons at midnight.

What may be happening?

-

My horizon.conf (php worker):

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=5
redirect_stderr=true
```

laravel-scheduler.conf

```
[program:laravel-scheduler]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/bin/sh -c "while [ true ]; do (php /var/www/artisan schedule:run --verbose --no-interaction &); sleep 60; done"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=5
user=laradock
redirect_stderr=true
```

Kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('cron:bonus_daily')->daily();
$schedule->command('cron:payout')->daily();
$schedule->command('cron:status')->everyFiveMinutes();
$schedule->command('cron:bonus_residual')->cron('0 0 */15 * *');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi for **cron** (`Task Scheduling`), laravel [suggests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#introduction) just running normal cron (Remove `laravel-scheduler.conf` from supervisor) and add:

```php
* * * * * cd /var/www/artisan && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Run: `crontab -e` (with `-u {your_user}` to edit cron for specific user, usually `www-data`), and add above line.

Because what happens now: `supervisor` starts the `scheduler`, it exists immediately, and supervisor will no longer keep it running, this is where you app breaks, also you spawn 5 processes for `Task Scheduling` is not needed, cron `Task Scheduling` should check if there are tasks per minute (this is lowest that cron can run).

And for **Queues** yes `supervisor`, and here you can spawn more processes.